# EE 2.6.0 Password Reset not working

Tags: ee2, login, password

I've been locked out of a site I'm developing as my password is no longer accepted.

What I've done so far.

1. Reset the password 10+ times
2. copied password hash from database of site I know works into password hash of site I can't access
3. generated an md5 hash and pasted in to password field
4. reset password again via /admin.php hash changed in database,but I still can't access
5. tried all of the above after clearing cookies
6. tried again in 3 different browsers

There are no other registered users that I can use to login, member registration has been turned off in the CP so I can't create a new user either.

Have also checked the exp_reset_password table and all values appear to be empty.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a php enabled template that's publicly accessible? (Or that can be made publicly accessible?)

If so the following code on the template *should* log you in as whatever member_id you specify.

```
$member_id = 1; // Or whatever your member ID is
$this->EE =& get_instance();
$this->EE->session->create_new_session($member_id);
```

Comment: If you don't have a php enabled template, you could just throw the code in a plugin, and then use the template tag on a non-php template.

Comment: Dave - no php enabled template. What else do I need in a plugin to make it work?

Comment: Kudo's to DAve for going above and beyond, wrote a plugin for me and delivered via skype

Comment: If anyone else runs into this, I put the plugin on devot:ee -- http://dvt.ee/logover