# Super Admin locked out of ExpressionEngine Control Panel (Zoo Visitor Addon)

Tags: login, zoo-visitor, super-admin, zoo

I appear to have been logged out and cannot log back in to the site.
Heres what I did:

1. Installed Zoo Visitor
2. created a new Clients member group
3. added a zoo visitor channel field to another channel (Notice
   Channel)
4. edited a Notice channel entry and added a new member to Clients from
   the zoo visitor field
5. It went straight to a grey Error page

Now I cannot log in with my super admin account.

Any ideas? Im pretty far into development of this site.

EE version 2.7.3
Zoo visitor version: latest.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging in using your Super Admin email address as your username?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your admin_session_type in the config file to $config['admin_session_type'] = 's'; and trying again... if 's' (session) doesn't do the trick try 'c' (cookie)

It might also be worth taking a peek at http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/216411/

If you locked out your account from some reason, you might have to clear out entries in the exp_password_lockout table for that user.

Comment: I've just empties the exp_password_lockout table with no luck.

Comment: I've Just seen that the addon Zoo Visitor isn't compatible with another addon on the site, this might be the issue..??

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is logging in, and that's it, you can change replace your password in the exp_members table with an md5 hash of a password, and then log in using the unhashed version of the password.

It's also possible to log yourself in programmatically (see [EE 2.6.0 Password Reset not working](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/ee-2-6-0-password-reset-not-working/9969#9969))

Comment: Hi thanks, I changed the password to a new MD5 hash and now the error has changed to "you are not authorised to perform this action" when I log in... Progress maybe? any further ideas?

Comment: I'd try the add-on (login override), or using the php code from my link to see if you can get into the control panel to change your password.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (locked out super admin account after installing Zoo Visitor and transferring members) and when I went into phpMyAdmin for my database and looked at the exp_members table, I saw that my super admin email address had been changed (one letter removed). I believe this was because I had two user accounts with the same email address -- my super admin account and an anonymous account used by a public channel form. The anonymous user kept my exact email address and the super admin user had a slightly modified version of the email address. Then I changed the anonymous user's email address in phpMyAdmin, logged in with my incorrect super admin email address, and changed my email address in the CP. I guess I could have changed that email address directly in the database, too, but I wanted to see if I could login.